# Nodejs Log-in Page

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am new to NodeJs and what to create a login page by Node JS and afterwards I want to authentication for login with the same.

Kindly let me know what all I should know to do a basic nodejs login page and how should I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this example made using express  which is  small framework for node.js

[Easy Node Authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)